# Why .net client profile does not appear in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

I have Visual Studio 2008 but I don't see in Application tab, Target Profile Client.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that's an SP1 feature.

Answer (score 1):

John is right, it is an SP1 feature. In SP1, it is on the Application "tab", underneath the Target Framework dropdown and is labelled "Client-only Framework subset".